# The new history mode "full" - how far back can you go to retrieve balances?

Tags: blockchain

Docs say:

> full nodes store all chain data since the beginning of the chain, but drop the archived contexts below the current checkpoint

Also, the docs mention the checkpoint is 5 cycles.  If that is the case it would seem that delegates should not use full/rolling, since we need to go back 7 cycles to get balances of all those who delegate to us?